# MySQLi result set chaning when running the same query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Having a fairly simple query

```
SELECT
    af_ad.*, af_ad_to_interest.interest_id
FROM af_ad
LEFT JOIN af_adlike ON af_adlike.ad_id = af_ad.ad_id
LEFT JOIN af_ad_to_interest ON af_ad_to_interest.ad_id = af_ad.ad_id
LEFT JOIN af_ad_stats ON af_ad_stats.ad_id = af_ad.ad_id
WHERE
    (af_adlike.user_id = 1 AND af_adlike.adlike_action = 1)
    AND af_ad.ad_deleted = 0 AND af_ad.ad_accepted = 1
GROUP BY af_ad.ad_id, af_ad_to_interest.interest_id
ORDER BY af_ad.ad_date_created DESC, af_ad.ad_id
```

results in a set that remains the same for most of the runs (query executions) but still somehow the result set happens to have changed <strike>row order</strike> in a few occasions (manual test, result set is relatively small ~2000 rows, happens ~5th time).

The respective PHP code is

```
$handle = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
$result = $handle->query($query);
```

Read about possible solutions here [about mysqli queries/parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), could passing/implementing an extra parameter `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` or using `mysqli_free_result`, closing connection, etc., could solve it?

**Edit 1:**

Here are the output arrays:

Most cases:

```
[0] => 15
[1] => 19
**[2] => 10**
[3] => 17
[4] => 12
[5] => 9
[6] => 16
[7] => 18
[8] => 9
[9] => 9
[10] => 12
[11] => 10
[12] => 11
[13] => 11
[14] => 18
[15] => 2
[16] => 20
```

Some cases:

```
[0] => 15
[1] => 19
[2] => 17
[3] => 12
[4] => 9
[5] => 16
**[6] => 10**
[7] => 18
[8] => 9
[9] => 9
[10] => 12
[11] => 10
[12] => 11
[13] => 11
[14] => 18
[15] => 2
[16] => 20
```

**Edit 2:**

Found another possible pitfall. I am running two queries sequentially, like

```
$result1 = $handle->query($query1);
$result2 = $handle->query($query2);
```

Could it be possible it somehow caches/stores the previous results (although the `$query1` and `$query2` are quite different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid having in SELECT columns that are not in GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
    af_ad.ad_id, af_ad_to_interest.interest_id, min(af_ad.ad_date_created) as min_ad_date_created
FROM af_ad
LEFT JOIN af_adlike ON af_adlike.ad_id = af_ad.ad_id
LEFT JOIN af_ad_to_interest ON af_ad_to_interest.ad_id = af_ad.ad_id
LEFT JOIN af_ad_stats ON af_ad_stats.ad_id = af_ad.ad_id
WHERE
    (af_adlike.user_id = 1 AND af_adlike.adlike_action = 1)
    AND af_ad.ad_deleted = 0 AND af_ad.ad_accepted = 1
GROUP BY af_ad.ad_id, af_ad_to_interest.interest_id
ORDER BY min_ad_date_created DESC, af_ad.ad_id;
```

Comment: Edited my question with your solution. Still getting the same results although another possible problem was pointed out.

Comment: Actually, if you've got GROUP BY then both SELECT and ORDER BY cannot have other expressions than the ones from GROUP BY plus aggregations (max, min, count...). MySQL allows otherwise, but the results are a bit random. Could you test my edited answer and post results?

Comment: You, sir, made my day! Forgot about the 'randomness in row order' when dealing (ordering) with equal values.